# Bash export directory head

Tags: bash, version-control, export

I'm given a line:

```
export WDIR_HEAD=${WDIR%%/*}
```

where WDIR is a user-input directory for a revision control system entry.  I realize export sets an environment variable, my question is just what the role of '%%/*' is here.

I need to rewrite this to run in python for a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special form of [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

> **${parameter%word}**
>   **${parameter%%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’
>   or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>   parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
>   parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
>   pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

As for `/*` it matches `/` or anything starting with it. See [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: To clarify for my specific situation, WDIR_HEAD would be the directory '/WDIR/.../...' ?? I'm a little confused what is meant by matching the 'trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter'.

Comment: @user2049004 It would be the value of WDIR with all that matches `/*` in the end of it deleted. e.g. `WDIR=/a/b/c; echo "${WDIR%%/*}"` shows nothing since everything is deleted. `%%` is greedy and gets the longest match. If you only do `${WDIR%/*}` it would just delete `/c` showing `/a/b`.